# How can I make Chrome shrink to fit on printing?

Tags: google-chrome, printing, zoom

I'd like to print a web document on a single page, but Chrome [famously doesn't have this feature](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/2chh9y/print_scaling_seriously_google_no_fix_for_years/) normally called *fit to page* or *shrink to fit*.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, there is a workaround. What we'll do is manually zoom the document with CSS until the contents fit appropriately.

Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to launch Chrome DevTools. Make sure it's on the tab **Elements** and the `<body>` element is selected. Now move to the **Styles** tab (on the right) and, in `element.style`, insert the following: (just click after the opening brace `{`)

```
zoom: 85%;
```

**Hint:** don't type the colon (`:`) else you'll inadvertently launch something else; instead, just hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> after typing `zoom`.

[image: css zoom property]

Now close DevTools (<kbd>F12</kbd> again) and hit <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> to launch the print dialog. Check to see if the page is fitting well. If it isn't, retry with another zoom value until it's good!

Comment: I can confirm in August 2016 this method works like a charm! `zoom: 85%` seems to be perfect for most pages that otherwise overflow in Chrome print preview. Thanks for posting this!

Comment: What is 85%? A magic number?

Comment: @Gherman it's just a first guess. Read until the end.

Comment: Well, I understand but will the same value work for any other machine? What does it depend on?

Comment: If you are a Web developer, you can add `zoom: 85%;` to the HTML element inside a `@media print` query.

Answer (score 10):

As of version 56 you now you will have an option for Scale in the print preview. However you may have to enable it (I have version 56.0.2924.87). In the Address bar: chrome://flags/#print-scaling and change it to Enabled.
This does not solve the "scale to fit" but does get you one step closer.

See this and more enhancements here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/O7nz6Vb1kBM

Comment: This is an easier solution

Comment: Cool! I'm on `58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)` and it works out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

I only have trouble on a few websites, for them I use the extension:

Full page screen capture

(https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl)

It creates a temporary image in a new tab which then scales correctly when you print that.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I want to print a whole webpage to a page of paper I do a screenshot of the page and use Windows to print the image.

Currently, I use [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/) to do the screenshot of the whole page. There are also [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/de/), [Awesome Screenshot](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/) and [Fireshot](http://getfireshot.com/) which worked for me.

[image: This question about to be printed]